# nginx - rewrite to HTTP or HTTPS in nginx.conf file

Tags: nginx

In nginx.conf file, is it possible to rewrite to HTTP or HTTPS based on whether the current connection is secured or not?

Some pseudocode of what I want to do.

```
location ^~ /test_api {
    if (secured connection)
        rewrite "/test_api"   https://www.somedomain.com/test_api     break;
    else
        rewrite "/test_api"   http://www.somedomain.com/test_api      break;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `$scheme`.

```
rewrite /test_api $scheme://www.example.com/test_api break;
```